# Libgdx freetype, app crashes without error on run

Tags: libgdx, aide

I have a default "new mobile game Java/libgdx" project.

I downloaded libgdx-freetype and extracted libgdx-freetype.jar and libgdx-freetype-natives.jar and the folders with the .so files to the `gdx-game` and `gdx-game-android` folders.

I modified .classpath files as at the bottom of this question.
I tried adding the line

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" exported="true" path="libs/gdx-freetype-natives.jar"/>
```

But that doesn't help. The app still crashes on first run with no debug log output.

The app compiles fine, and the editor recognises and autocompletes the classes.   Its when I click run that it crashes. "the app has stopped working"

I tried long pressing the .jars but that only gives me the option to remove from project.

I tried restarting AIDE but that didnt help either.

What do I need to change to get libgdx-freetype to work with my AIDE project?

Gdx-game

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" exported="true" path="libs/gdx.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" exported="true" path="libs/gdx-freetype.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

Gdx-game-android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" exported="true" path="/gdx-game" combineaccessrules="false"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" exported="true" path="/gdx-game/libs/gdx.jar" />
    <classpathentry kind="lib" exported="true" path="/gdx-game/libs/gdx-freetype.jar" />
    <classpathentry kind="lib" exported="true" path="libs/gdx-backend-android.jar" />
</classpath>
```

Comment: Have you tried it on desktop just to make sure it's android specific?

Comment: I'm developing it with AIDE, an env that runs on mobile. I'm not doing this on a desktop or a system that has desktop access. I'm interested in a solution that will let AIDE include the extra library in the created android application with the settings as described above

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by having `gdx-freetype-natives.jar` in the libs folder.

Removing the jar allows the program to run.

*Note*
However, a secondary issue is that it's compiled with a too new issue of java, trying to access methods on classes that don't exist yet. But thats another issue that can probaly be solved by getting the older files from the github.